# What is the purpose of having ".nextDouble" after storing an input?

Tags: java, input, calculator

After programming in C++ for a few months, and getting to an intermediate level, I decided to start learning Java. I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around how the scanner variable works. In C++, "cin>>" was very straightforward in the fact that it would store whatever the input was, into a previously declared variable. However, in Java a variable itself is a scanner? How does that work? Also, what is the purpose of having ".nextDouble" after telling the scanner where to store the variable? I learned it from a tutorial, and here's my code below.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class calculator {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
     double fnum, snum, answer;
     System.out.println("Enter first number: ");
     fnum = var.nextDouble();
     System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
     snum = var.nextDouble();
     answer = fnum+snum;
     System.out.println(answer);


 }
     }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var` is a reference to a `Scanner` [object](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/object.html) that helps abstract the reading of tokenized input from a source (in this case the default input stream, [`System.in`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#in)).

The call to [`.nextDouble()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextDouble%28%29) waits for a value to be inputted (e.g. from a prompt, or piped into stdin). Once input, the value will be stored in the assigned property (i.e. `fnum` or `snum`).

If the value's not parseable as a `double`, an `InputMismatchException` will be thrown.

Here's a briefly annotated version of your source that explains what's happening:

```
 // Create a new Scanner object that will read input from System.in (stdin).
 Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);

 // Declare some variables. The scanner hasn't done anything significant yet.
 double fnum, snum, answer;

 // Print a line to stdout.
 System.out.println("Enter first number: ");

 // Block until the scanner (i.e. stdin) receives a token. By default, the
 // Scanner will use whitespace to tokenize anything that comes in on
 // System.in. nextDouble() will try to parse the first available token
 // into a double. If the parsing succeeds, assign the parsed value to fnum.
 fnum = var.nextDouble();

 // Same thing as above, but for snum.
 System.out.println("Enter second number: ");
 snum = var.nextDouble();

 ...
```

It may not hurt to read through the [class documentation for Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) to help provide some context about what a Scanner is and how it works.

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to annotate the code for me, this really helped! So in summary, the ".nextDouble" is kind of like a prompt for the program to hold everything until "the next double" is inputted?

Comment: To a degree. It depends on the source of the input. In this case, it'll probably block and wait for input if you run it at the command line. If you've piped something into stdin, it probably won't block since it'll already have something to tokenize. If your source is something other than a stream (see the docs), it probably won't block, either.

Answer (score 5):

```
  Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
```

At this point values won't be read. Assume like this opens a stream (or) pipe between console and your program.

```
fnum = var.nextDouble();
```

Tells JVM that, now go and get the next available `double` value from the stream named as `var` (java terminology, reference) and store that value to `fnum`.

Comment: Thanks much for the concise answer!

Answer (score 2):

Calling `var.nextDouble()` causes the next `double` value to be read from the input and its value returned. You then need to store the value somewhere (or not, if you just want to throw it away). There's no place where you are "telling the scanner where to store the variable".

Answer (score 2):

Something that a person who knows C++ at an "intermediate level" should know: `cin` is a global variable, `>>` is a method call masquerading as an operator, and the "variable" is a reference parameter of that method call.

In Java there are no unqualified global variables, method calls follow the `object.method(params)` format, and there's no pass-by-reference.

Answer (score 1):

nextDouble() is a method of the class Scanner that returns the next scanned double. Basically the class Scanner is doing the cin type stuff for you but you don't see the inner workings of it. It's as if you wrote a class in C++ to handle the cin for you and now you are just using that class.

Comment: But it's not doing the `cin` stuff: unlike `cin`, the output location isn't passed to the scanner. It's important to be clear about that because it's a point of confusion for C++ programmers new to Java.

Comment: my point was just that its a black box so no need to really worry about it... but you are right.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yeah, in C++, like the first answer pointed out, I never really learned that "cin" was a global variable, and it was doing all the work that we see in Java, in one or two operators.

Answer (score 1):

Here as a beginner it is okay that you got confused. First thing is why we use `scanner`?. We use `scanner class` when the program wants to get an `user input`. just like program asks you "what is your name?" you type Peter. Then program can respond you as "Hello `Peter`!". There you enter your name which is a string value, 
When you use scanner you get user inputs and you need variables to store those inputs. you can say "name" is the variable. so what ever name you enter will get stored in name variable. Now how system take your that particular answer? for that there are some methods we use. for a 
`string` we will use `var.next()` ,
`double` --> `var.nextDouble()`,
`int` ---->  `nextInt()`,

where `var` is in `Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);` the scanner reference variable name.

in your example you are expecting double values as user inputs so that's why you are saying `JVM` to get the next double value.